# Error when selecting the number of features to be used to SVC classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on this project in this site

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html with the Iris dataset

However when I try to implement

```
X = iris.data[:, :2]
```

an error comes saying

```
File "`<pyshell#16>"`, line 1, in <module>
    X = iris.data[:, :2]
NotImplementedError: multi-dimensional slicing is not implemented
```

Can someone tell me why this is and what can I do to avoid this please

Comment: What does `type(iris.data)` report? How about `iris.data.shape`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the format of the data might have changed.

`load_iris` seems to load the data as a dictionary.

This should work:

```
iris = load_iris()
X = iris['data'][:, :2]
y = iris['target']
```